Уведомление на сайте wordpress
Не понимаю как можно сделать уведомление на сайте с wordpress без плагинов. Нужно, что бы при значении true (переменной) на странице выводилось уведомление.


По типу таких. Я видел что есть функция wp_admin_notice(), но, как я понял, работает она только в админке.

Используйте PHP:
if($var == true){
echo 'show_class';
}

